# How to intercept Spring Data JPA repository?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, aop, aspectj

I'm using `Spring Data JPA`, and I have to intercept all of the entity event.
Unfortunately, I can't use entity listener like `@PreUpdate`, `@PostLoad`.
So I'm trying to write AOP.
Everything is okay, but intercepting `update` is problem.
There is no `update` method in JPA as you know.

So I was exploring `hibernate` code, and I've found pretty good `PointCut` named `CallbackRegistry` in `hibernate` library.
So I did like this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.jpa.CallbackRegistry+.pre*(..))")
public void callback() { }
```

But as you know, in Spring AOP, it doesn't work.
Because `CallbackRegistry` is not `Spring bean`.
So I'm trying to `AspectJ`, but I don't know how can I do.

Is this right approach? And.. if I'm right, can you let me know how can I do?

Comment: why can't you use proper event listeners? What you are trying to do sounds really brittle and hacky.

Comment: If you want to use AOP on non-Spring managed beans then investigate using AspectJ. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-vs-aspectj